# Function to change path in different <script src="path"> tag

Tags: javascript, html

Im not sure if it is possible to reach the src of a different script tag.

```
</head>
<script src="./data.json"></script>
<script>
//my functions
```

I want to make a button or similar which changes "./data.json" to something else and reload the page.

Comment: If you reload the page, you'll discard the DOM change you just made

Comment: Instead, load the json with `fetch` or similar

Comment: @bambam could you please explain how to use fetch for this?

Comment: I've added an answer that demonstrates how to live update your site's content based on json data

Answer (score 0):

Here's a dirty example on how to use fetch to live update data within a table (for the sake of the example) from json data. You can adapt that easily to your needs (but don't use the strings to create html, instead use document.createElement and so on...

```js
const url = "https://randomuser.me/api/?results=10"; // returns json data

function getData() {
  fetch(url).then(res => res.json()).then(({
    results
  }) => {
    const body = document.querySelector('#foo tbody');
    body.innerHTML = "";
    results.forEach(({
      name
    }) => {
      const strHTML = `<tr><td>${name.title}</td><td>${name.last}</td><td>${name.first}</td></tr>`;
      body.innerHTML += strHTML;
    })
  });
}
getData();
setInterval(getData, 2000);
```

```html
<table id="foo">
  <thead>
    <th>gender</th>
    <th>name</th>
    <th>firstName</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score -1):

I have no idea why you would change the `src` attribute, and why even reload the page then. Changing the `src` attrbute won't change the script. You must instead create a new script element with the new `src`. Add an `id` attribute to the script tag. Select the script tag using that ID, delete it and create a new script.

**HTML**

```
<script id="x" src="./data.json"></script>
```

**JavaScript**

```
var oldScript = document.getElementById("x");
oldScript.parentElement.removeChild(oldScript);

var newScript = document.createElement("script");
newScript.src = "something else";
document.body.appendChild(newScript);
```

If you need to permanently change the `src` attribute (such that the change stands after reloading the page), you should use some server-side technology that is capable of reading/writing to local files.